# Is it possible to Map the Keys of an EnumMap to Columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enums

Is it possible to map the keys of a Map with only a fixed amount of possible keys like an EnumMap to columns in a table using jpa/hibernate.

I am not trying to store the enum with two columns (one for the key and one for the value) but trying to create a column for each enum key.

Would this even be a good idea?

For additional context: I have multiple Integers in the Entity that are always accessed in the same fashion and need to also be accessed using an Enum. So i could add the Integer A, B and C to the Entity but then i would need to always use a switch statement to select the correct one. Saving the 
Enum/Integer mapping in its own relation, as is possible with jpa, seems to be an overkill when it would be possible to do it in the way described.

Imagine having the following Enum and ElementCollection inside of an Entity.

```java
public enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    //... id and other fields

    @ElementCollection
    private final Map<SomeEnum, Integer> amounts;
}
```

Expected Table Structure for SomeEntity:

### ID | A | B | C

### 0 | 0 | 3 | 5

### 1 | 2 | 1 | 0

Comment: from my perspective it is not a good idea, imagine you extend the enum, usually you would map the enum to a string field on the database, but mapping them to columns would require to extend the table on each new enum (adding complexity on deployment phase)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. 

You are right that expanding the enum would require a change in the database layout. But so would adding a new field. I have edited the original post to provide more context. In short: i have multiple Integer fields in the entity that should be selected using the Enum. Adding a new Integer would require a change in the Enum, the Entity and the selection logic that switches between the Integers. 

I think that actually Mapping the Enum the way you described would be overkill as we are talking about max 5 different fields.

Comment: I understand your point, but then why using enums and not a simple @Embeddable class containing the max 5 Integer properties?

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. This is the way i implemented it now.